# How to read first line of a file twice?

Tags: python, file, iterator

I have a big files with many lines and want to read the first line first and then loop through all lines starting with the first line again.

I first thought that something like that would do it:

```
file = open("fileName", 'r')
first_line = file.readline()
DoStuff_1(first_line)

for line in file:
   DoStuff_2(line)

file.close()
```

But this issue with this script is that the first line that is passed to `DoStuff_2` is the second line and not the first one. I don't have a good intuition of what kind of object `file` is. I think it is an iterator and don't really know how to deal with it. The bad solution I found is

```
file = open("fileName", 'r')
first_line = file.readline()

count = 0
for line in file:
   if count == 0:
      count = 1
      DoStuff_1(first_line)
   DoStuff_2(line)

file.close()
```

But it is pretty dumb and is computationally a bit costly as it runs a if statement at each iteration.

Comment: `open` returns a generator in python. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
with open('fileName', 'r') as file:
    first_line = file.readline()
    DoStuff_1(first_line)
    DoStuff_2(first_line)

    # remaining lines
    for line in file:
        DoStuff_2(line)
```

Note that I changed your code to use `with` so `file` is automatically closed.

Comment: Ha ha well that was so obvious! I guess thta when you're in the middle of more complicated code you miss the obvious but once the problem is reduced to its essential elements for a question the answer was really evident. Thank you. I didn't use `with` because I didn't know if the object `file` would then exist in the environment of every function called within the `with` function. Is it? I currently just defined `file` as global.

Comment: @Remi.b That's what Stack Overflow is for, in my opinion: letting other people see past our blind spots. As for the use of `with`: I just assumed that the usage in your question was the first time `file` was assigned to, in which case using `with` is good practice. If `file` is used in other places as well, you'll need to look more into what exact solution to use.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like using a generator to abstract your general control flow. Something like:

```
def first_and_file(file_obj):
    """
    :type file_obj: file
    :rtype: (str, __generator[str])
    """
    first_line = next(file_obj)

    def gen_rest():
        yield first_line
        yield from file_obj

    return first_line, gen_rest()
```

In Python 2.7, swap out the `yield from` for:

```
for line in file_obj:
    yield line
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer is to just open the file twice.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as r:
    Do_Stuff1(r.readline())

with open("file.txt", "r") as r:
    for line in r:
        Do_Stuff2(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions for a general case of this question is to save the line number on which you are. After completing an operation which requires you to go a previous line relative to the current line, use the line number variable by doing file.seek(0) and then looping over file.readline() the required number of times.